# Как в wordpress выбрать только те записи, которые содержат "featured image" при помощи wp_query?

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте! Возникла некая проблема при выводе последних постов на главной странице сайта, вот к примеру: 
у меня есть новости, на главной странице выводятся две последние, но они там должны быть только с картинками, но не обязательно в каждой новостной записи будет картинка, собственно и вопрос, как выбрать из базы только те, которые имеют "featured image".
Спсибо!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

[Источник (см. "#5 Получим записи у которые есть произвольное поле")](http://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#parametry-proizvolnyh-polej-postmeta)

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало)

Answer (score 0):

плагин Page-list
[pagelist_ext show_content = "0" image_width="200" image_height="200"]

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые ответы.